# C: Using sprintf( ) to do IP address parse, incorrect value

Tags: c, parsing, printf

I was trying to use `sprintf()` to parse IP address. `buf` storing a packet received from other host. And the test data in `buf` is `'\0xff'`. I expect to see `255.255.255.255` in `ip`. But what I get is `-1.-1.-1.-1` in `ip`.

```
char buf[5];
char ip[18];
...
// They all have value 0xff, that is buf[0]=buf[1]=buf[2]=buf[3]='\0xff';
sprintf(ip, "'%d.%d.%d.%d'",buf[0],buf[1],buf[2],buf[3]);
```

It seems in every byte in `buf` it is added by one. I think it should be something with the specifier, maybe I should use a specifier for `unsigned int`. Then I tried `%u`, `%hhd`. They are not correct. Anyone knows this? Is it because of the specifier?

Comment: did you try `unsigned char....`

Comment: That isn't parsing an IP address, it's formatting one. It is the exact opposite.

Comment: Note: `ip[18]` is too small had test data been `'\0x80'`: `"'-128.-128.-128.-128'"`.  Better to use `snprintf()` or oversize `buf` as output may be more than expected.  Since `"%d"` _could_ print a number like `"-2147483648"`, better to assume the worst.

Comment: @chux: with `buf` correctly defined as an `unsigned char` it can only hold values in the range 0-255 (assuming a normal byte=8bits=char system). So the maximum length of `ip` will be 16 characters: four 3-digit values + three dot separators + a null terminator.

Comment: @GrahamS  1) `buf` was not defined as `unsigned char` yet and did not invoke UB as `buf` was not `'\0x80'`, else this post would have UB.  OP had _assumed_ something that did not hold true.  Your comment continues with assumptions of 8-bit `unsigned char` and C locale for `sprintf()`.  Even though both reasonable assumptions, `sprintf()` is an unwieldy function.  Your 16 does not reflect OP's format of `"'%d.%d.%d.%d'"` which would need 18.  So had OP used 16 as you had computed, code would certainly have UB.

Comment: @GrahamS  (cont) The larger point is that there is little need to _tightly_ minimize buffer size.  Instead buffer size should be computed via the code with few assumptions.  Maybe `sizeof format + 4*MAX_INT_WIDTH + 1`, or better yet, use `snprintf()`.

Comment: @chux: thanks I missed the apostrophes in the OPs post - that explains where they got 18 from. However I complete disagree with over-allocating the buffer just in case. On a system with 32-bit ints that would end up creating a buffer of 50 characters for something that cannot be larger than 18 unless there are programming errors. I'd agree that using `snprintf()` is a reasonable defence though, or better still use the proper `inet` libraries as @PSkocik and I also suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `buf` declared as a `signed char`.
You see `-1` because `0xFF` is `11111111` in binary which is `-1` in [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Declare `buf` as an unsigned char instead, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char buf[4] = { 0xFF, 0xEE, 0xDD, 0xFF };
    char ip[18];

    sprintf(ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3]);

    printf (ip);

    return 0;
}
```

Depending on your target platform, you might want to look at libraries that do all this for you. For example [inet_ntoa(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa)

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't really answer the question as GrahamS has already answered it well, but you might want to try using the functions and structs of the TCP/IP stack that were made for this kind of thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main()
{
  /*
   * Using functions and structs that were made for this
   */

  //this is really just a one-member struct with a  uint_32t
  struct in_addr addr;

  //Convert Presenteation to Number (pton) for the AF_INET address family (IPv4)
  inet_pton(AF_INET,"1.2.3.4",&addr);


  //INET_ADDRSTRLEN -- how much space is needed to hold the presentation of an IP4 ip addresss?
  //defined to 16 -- enough to hold 255.255.255.255 with the null terminator
  char buf[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]; 

  //convert back to string
  inet_ntop(AF_INET,&addr, buf, sizeof(buf));

  puts(buf);
    return 0;
}
```